# Grammar rules for "I would rather be a lonely man than to play"

Tags: grammar

I searched all over the internet and always found contradicting answers concerning the following topic.

In this sentence:

> I would rather be alone than to go out tonight.

if I apply grammar rules it would have to be "than go out tonight", 
but I found a lot of people who saw nothing wrong with the first version. I want to be sure about it and get a correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I'd always omit *to*. The idiom is "I'd rather *X* than *Y*."

"I'd rather X than to Y" breaks parallelism.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner

Comment: He has found contradicting statements about it.  Opinions aren't what he is looking for.  I would suggest that you back yourself up with rules or at least some sort of indication that yours is the popular opinion.

Comment: thank you , but what was wrong with : " thank you for your attention " even if Idid not have your attention yet  !

Comment: What? Oh, you're referring to zondo's edit of your post. There's nothing at all wrong with "Thank you for your attention." Perhaps it's unnecessary, but it's perfectly correct and appropriate.

Comment: thanhs again to all of you !